# Jquery To get substring from a long string within two specific sub strings

Tags: jquery, values

I have a long string as - " [https://example.com/js-form-name-62682.html?ref=https%3A%2F%2Fstaging.example.com%2sample%3Fsku%3D40567&*referrer*=embeddedtype-and-somemortext](https://example.com/js-form-name-62682.html?ref=https%3A%2F%2Fstaging.example.com%2sample%3Fsku%3D40567&_referrer_=embeddedtype-and-somemortext) "

I want to get the value 40567 i.e the test which comes up withing sku%3D and &_referrer with jquery.

How can I get this ?

Please provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

var MainString = "[https://example.com/js-form-name-62682.html?ref=https%3A%2F%2Fstaging.example.com%2sample%3Fsku%3D40567&*referrer*=embeddedtype-and-somemortext](https://example.com/js-form-name-62682.html?ref=https%3A%2F%2Fstaging.example.com%2sample%3Fsku%3D40567&_referrer_=embeddedtype-and-somemortext)";

var subStringVal = MainString.substring(
    MainString.lastIndexOf("3D") + 2, 
    MainString.lastIndexOf("&_referrer")
);

It gives - 40567